# Exempt / Exclude Tax for a particular customer group in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, tax, tax-class, tax-calculation

I want to Exempt / Exclude Tax for a particular customer group in Magento 2.2.
Could you pls help me out

Comment: For not applying the tax to a particular customer group make sure that you haven't included that customer group into the tax rule that you have created & to test this make sure you are accessing the front-end from the user which belongs to the excepted user group.

Comment: Ya, I have checked twice and checked the customer assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign tax rules to customer group as per following steps.

https://www.customerparadigm.com/how-to-assign-tax-rules-to-a-customer-group-in-magento-2/

For example you can create wholesaler customer group and set no tax (zero) for it.

Comment: @KishanI have created a Tax rule and Tax Rate but still tax is including. Could u guide me pls? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check customer group of that customer in backend. Update it if necessary.

Comment: I have checked and customer group Tax Class is set correctly.